# Qt : addToJavaScriptWindowObject and switch QWebView content

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview

I'm using `QWebView` for displaying some of my html content. I use multiple html pages and i must switch between them and apply the `addJavaScriptWindowObject` method on it to load my C++ object. 
At the moment i'm using this function to load a new html page :

```
Q_INVOKABLE bool                myBridge::newView(QString page)
{
    QString path("file:///C:/wamp/www/WLC_Borne/");

    path += page;
    _view->close();
    _view = new WebView;
    QObject::connect(_view, SIGNAL(mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*)), _mediaPlayer, SLOT(stop()));
    _view->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("bridge", this);
    _view->load(QUrl(path));
    _view->showFullScreen();
    return (true);
}
```

The problem is that i'm always allocating a new `QWebView` and it adds like 5ko to the process memory usage for each new one.

The reason why i create a new `QWebView` is that with only doing :

```
_view->page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("bridge", this);
        _view->load(QUrl(path));
        _view->showFullScreen();
```

the `addToJavaScriptWindowObject` doesnt apply on the page. I have to make a new webview to make it works.
My question was it a clean way of switching between html pages and make it works with `addToJavaScriptWindowObject` method on each new page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to connect your page to a slot like this if you want the method `addToJavaScriptWindowObject` to work. Something like this :

```
bool myBridge::newView( QString page )
{
    _view->close();
    _view = new WebView;
    QObject::connect(_view, SIGNAL(mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*)), _mediaPlayer, SLOT(stop()));
    QObject::connect( _view->page()->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()), this, SLOT(addObject()));
    _view->load(QUrl(path));
    _view->showFullScreen();
}

void myBridge::addObject()
{
    frame->addToJavaScriptWindowObject( QString("bridge"), this );
}
```